# how to check if the experimental performance of the oscillation amplitudes follows the predicted trend?

Tags: experimental-physics

once I got my set of amplitudes how can I compare experimental amplitudes with damped harmonic motion?

I know that

$F = -kx + mg -(C_1 + C_2 |v|)v  $

supposing c2 = 0 and cos = 1

$x(t) = Ae^{-\gamma t} $

supposing c1 = 0

$x(t) = \frac{A_0}{1+A_0 \alpha t}     , \alpha = \frac{4}{3\pi}C_2 \frac{w_0^2}{k}$

[image]

Comment: I want to understand is how to compare my experimental data with these 2 situations (C2 = 0, C1 = 0) and find the relative coefficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In essence you are trying to decide whether the friction forve is proportional to the velocity or velocity squared.

Assume that the period of a swing $T$ stays constant.

If $x(t)=A_oe^{-\gamma t}$ then if after $n$ swings the amplitude is $A_n$

$A_n = A_o e^{-\gamma T n} \Rightarrow \ln A_n = -\gamma T n + \ln A_o$, so plot a graph of $\ln A_n$ against $n$.

If $x(t) = \dfrac {A_o}{1+ A_o \alpha t}$ then if after $n$ the amplitude is $A_n$

$A_n = \dfrac {A_o}{1+ A_o \alpha T n} \Rightarrow \dfrac {1}{A_n} = \alpha T n + \dfrac {1}{A_o} $, so plot a graph of $\dfrac {1}{A_n}$ against $n$.

Comment: is it normal that  $\gamma$ increases every time, if I do $\frac{InA_0 - In A_n}{Tn} = \gamma$

Comment: The formula which you quote will enable you to get a series of values of $\gamma$ for different values of $n$.

Comment: it should be a constant shouldn't it?

Comment: Gamma will be constant if the frictional force depends linearly on the velocity.